# Поиск литературы, для написания сайта с определённым функционалом

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу написать простенький сайт для личного пользования (в играх D&D).

Функционал примерно следующий, есть окно с персонажем, есть возможность поменять экипировку, уровень, улучшение и т.п (это не так важно) и узнать характеристики в зависимости от выбранных ранее параметров.

Вот практически идеальный пример (калькулятор персонажа) - https://wsdb.xyz/calc/ru

У меня есть опыт в программировании на python, но с такими задачами я не сталкивался, да и джанго не особо хочется трогать. Как я понимаю мне понадобится подучить html и css, а для реализации всего функционала javasript. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать насколько это будет сложно и какую литературу стоит прочесть для того, что бы хватило навыков создать именно такой сайт.

Comment: На вопрос "насколько сложно" вам никто не сможет ответить достоверно т.к. это индивидуально и зависит от имеющихся знаний базы :) судя по вашему непониманию как это работает - для вас будет сложно :) читать начинать с основ html / js / css

Comment: До программирования, вам еще нужно будет собрать информацию о игре и поместить ее в какую-то базу.. Далее нужно получить формулы расчетов, например, если добавить +1 выносливости, уровень жизни повысится на 5 очков и так далее... 
Знания HTML и CSS вам конечно понадобятся, но это не так критично как javascript, который будет манипулировать данными и тд (я бы выбрал VueJS в данном случае).. 
В общем, если вы никогда не сталкивались с разработкой сайтов - вам будет очень сложно. В качестве учебного задания делать разве что...